# How to center a button in React

Tags: reactjs

I have tried the following, but it does not work

```
<button style = {{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}} onClick = {this.scream} >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `flexDirection` and `alignItems` in the element's container, not in the element itself.

You can learn more about `flex` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex